# Error when using pgsql2shp

Tags: postgis, shapefile, export, pgsql2shp

I try to export geographical data from a postgis database to a shapefile with pgsql2shp.

Normally this works fine, but now I receive the following error.

```
Preparing table for user query... Done. 
Initializing... ZMflagQuery: ERROR:  function zmflag(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT max(zmflag("geometrie"::geometry)) FROM "__pgsql2shp7...
```

The query I use is:

```
pgsql2shp.exe -f 'foldername' -h luna -p 5432 -u user-P pw -g geometrie dbname "select * from bag.adressen a where a.wnpcode = '3386'"
```

I haven't had any earlier problems with pgsql2shp.

Comment: You'll want to provide more information before anyone can give an informed answer.  What is the output from: SELECT postgis_full_version();

Comment: Output for SELECT postgis_full_version() = 
"POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.1, released 2012/05/15 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostGIS 2.0 doesn't have the function zmflag(geometry).  It is now known as st_zmflag(geometry).  I'm betting that the version of pgsql2shp is from a prior version of PostGIS.  You can check with

```
pgsql2shp -?
```

At the top of the output, it should list the release version. Something like...

```
RELEASE: 2.1.0SVN (r10420)
```