# Generating Shapefiles from PostGIS as a Plugin

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, pgsql2shp

I used to generate shapefile from PostgreSQL database that is installed with PostGIS tables as  templates (`geometry_columns` and `spatial_ref_sys`)

Shapefiles generated just fine using the following command:

```
 $pgsql2shp -f <path to new shapefile> -g <geometry column name> \   -h <hostname> -U <username> "<query>"
```

No I have a new database with PostGIS 2.0 which installed as a plugin. There is no PostGIS templates. So when I tried generating shapefiles using the above command I got the following error:

[image]

Any idea how can i export shapefiles in this case?

Comment: i think [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35660/55203) might help.. you might need to upgrade your version of pgsql2shp.

Comment: Thanks Steven! I think this is my problem and I'd appreciate it if you let me know how can I upgrade pgsql2shp. I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: How did you install PostGIS binaries - from a package and if so which one?  you might just be using the wrong version or  have two.  Also Linux distros often have the client utils in a separate package, so it's possible you didn't install the accompanying PostGIS client tools

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I installed it from a package. PostGIS version is 2.1.5 while pgsql2shp version is 1.5. So I guess I should upgrade pgsql2shp? or should I install it? I appreciate it if you let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just needed to load legacy support in PostGIS:

In my case:

`$psql -d DBName -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.1/legacy.sql`